# Call a php function from inside echo onclick without JS

Tags: php, function, parameter-passing

Looked through some other peoples questions however the replies suggest using JS; however due to the parameters for this project; I don't believe thats viable for me.
***Do not use JavaScript/CSSto hide/track/manipulate your data.***
anyways I'm echoing this in side of a `<?php ?>` block:

```
<a href="" onclick="addToRecentlyViewed("'.$row["productName"].'")">
    <img class="img-rounded img-thumbnail" src="products/' . $row["picture"] . '"/>
</a>
```

And above it I have another `<?php ?>` block that has:

```
function addToRecentlyViewed($productName){
                
    // If the cookie is already set lets work with whats in there.
    if( isset($_COOKIE['recentlyViewedProducts'])){
        $products = explode(',',$_COOKIE["recentlyViewedProducts"]);
                    
        // Max of 4 items in the list.
        if(sizeof($products) >= 4){
            // Start -> red, green, blue, yellow and adding purple
            //$products[0] = $products[1];
            //$products[1] = $products[2];
            //$products[2] = $products[3];
            //$products[3] = $productName;
            //end -> green, blue, yellow, purple.
            //$newList = join(",",$products);
        }
        // If less than 4 then just add.
        else{       
            // Just append to list.
            //$newList = $_COOKIE["recentlyViewedProducts"];
            //$newList .= ',' . $productName;
            //setcookie["recentlyViewedProducts", $newList];
        }
    }
    // If its not set lets set up the cookie.
    else{
        echo ' HELLO! ';
        setcookie('recentlyViewedProducts', $productName);
    }
}
```

I can't even get it to `echo ' HELLO! '` so I'm thinking I might be doing something wrong :(

***ADDED SOME CODE:***

```
</body>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
    
    $(function addToRecentlyViewed($productName){
        <?php
            // If the cookie is already set lets work with whats in there.
            if( isset($_COOKIE['recentlyViewedProducts'])){
                $products = explode(',',$_COOKIE["recentlyViewedProducts"]);
                
                // Max of 4 items in the list.
                if(sizeof($products) >= 4){
                    // Start -> red, green, blue, yellow and adding purple
                    $products[0] = $products[1];
                    $products[1] = $products[2];
                    $products[2] = $products[3];
                    $products[3] = $productName;
                    //end -> green, blue, yellow, purple.
                    $newList = join(",",$products);
                }
                // If less than 4 then just add.
                else{       
                    // Just append to list.
                    //$newList = $_COOKIE["recentlyViewedProducts"];
                    //$newList .= ',' . $productName;
                    //setcookie["recentlyViewedProducts", $newList];
                }
            }
            // If its not set lets set up the cookie.
            else{
                setcookie('recentlyViewedProducts', $productName);
            }
            ?>
        }
    )
</script>
```

This does create the cookie; but it says its deleted automatically. Should I just use infinite time...? Also I've never used these

```
<script> $(function xxx){} \</script>
```

I'm not breaking the no JS rule am I?

Comment: You cannot execute a PHP function via an `onclick` handler. PHP runs server-side, JavaScript rund client-side. `onclick` attributes are for JavaScript handlers.

Comment: `onclick` is a client event so that only works with JS (which is executed client side). If you want to trigger a PHP script, you need to use an ordinary link (put the URL to the PHP file in the links `href`) which will redirect the client to that page when clicked. You might be able to add an iframe (with width and height set to 0) with an id and set the link target to that iframe if you don't want the client to be redirected.

Comment: @ConstantinGroß Yea thats what I've been reading,and it makes sense but I don't think I'm allowed to use JS for this :L

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Not really sure what an iframe is :o kind of new around here I did manage to come with something that at least hits the function now though re: my edit :)

Comment: That's why you shouldn't use `onclick`! ;-) As @MagnusEriksson said: Use the `href` to pass a `GET` parameter that you can react to

Comment: If the code is to track viewed products, you could simply add that code on the product page itself, so when someone lands on a product page, the first thing you do is to run your PHP function before you show the contents.

Comment: @ConstantinGroß Alrighty; I'll give that a try unless you think my edit is worth persuing.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I tried that prof reminded me that product.php is used to display the product only nothing else. So that was a no go :/

Comment: Who's giving you all these ridiculous restrictions and to what end? If they tie your hands behind your back, you can't really be expected to be able to use them. The restrictions are basically hindering you from doing what you're asking about.

Comment: Those `<script>` tags are also JavaScrpipt, that you're not supposed to be using... ;-)

Comment: @ConstantinGroß I thought they might be... They're were supplied in the start package for this project so I doubt the prof will nail me for it; but now I'm going to ask him; thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson prof for the php course; and yea I think its a bit much but I get why he wants us to use php since its the php course lol. And it actually says:
Use JS and take an automatic 0
So I'm not about to mess around; espically since its a final and worth a big %

Comment: Sure, but they aren't allowing you to use PHP either since _"product.php is used to display the product only nothing else"_. Either you've misunderstood the requirements, or your professor has given you a very unrealistic scenario which, imho, is nonsense.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson This is a direct quote from our instructions:
***The product page does nothing but pull up information on that clicked-on item***.
So yea I agree its pretty unrealistic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MagnusEriksson and @ConstantinGroß for the help
created a separate page so instead of onclick launch function it redirects to a page that sets up the cookies and looks like this:

```
<?php 

    function addToRecentlyViewed($productName){
        //If the cookie is already set lets work with whats in there.
        if( isset($_COOKIE['recentlyViewedProducts'])){
            $products = explode(',',$_COOKIE["recentlyViewedProducts"]);
            
            //Max of 4 items in the list.
            if(sizeof($products) >= 4){
                //Start -> red, green, blue, yellow and adding purple
                $products[0] = $products[1];
                $products[1] = $products[2];
                $products[2] = $products[3];
                $products[3] = $productName;
                //end -> green, blue, yellow, purple.
                $newList = join(",",$products);
                setcookie("recentlyViewedProducts",$newList);
            }
            //If less than 4 then just add.
            else{
                //Just append to list.
                $newList = $_COOKIE["recentlyViewedProducts"];
                $newList .= ',' . $productName;
                setcookie("recentlyViewedProducts", $newList);
            }
        }
        //If its not set lets set up the cookie.
        else{
            echo 'woo hoo!';
            setcookie('recentlyViewedProducts', $productName);
        }
        
    }
    
    addToRecentlyViewed($_GET["productName"]);
    header('location: product.php?product='.$_GET["productName"]);
?>
```

Best of luck to all :D